# Getting Chinese mainland travel permit as a Hong Kong citizen with dual nationalty

Tags: visas, china, dual-nationality, hong-kong-citizens

I'm a French citizen and also a Hong Kong citizen. I was born in HK but I lived for all my life in France. I got the HK residency card because of my birth.

I want to get a chinese mainland travel permit to make my trips to China, easier and less costly.

While discussing with some friends, they said because I have dual citizenship and I've used my French passport previously in China, China will not let me apply to the travel permit anymore because of new laws that were passed recently, barring citizens with dual nationalties and who have travelled with the other passport (French one for me) to apply.

Checking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainland_Travel_Permit_for_Hong_Kong_and_Macao_Residents#Issues_faced_by_other_foreign_passport_holders), there are no such issues mentioned but I maybe wrong.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Hong Kong citizen". Do you mean that you are a Chinese (PRC) citizen with Hong Kong permanent residency (e.g. because you are of Chinese descent and born in Hong Kong)?

Comment: @user102008 2nd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the whole thing is not very clear and be aware that it will take a major while (half a year is not a bad estimate, some travels to HK possibly as well) to get your "Home Return Permit" (HRP). Also it does not help that rules changed some years ago.

Most of what I am writing is based on forum entries [here](https://geoexpat.com/forum/54/thread120281-2.html) and [here](https://answers.travelchinaguide.com/question/393133.htm), so no official info and not from my personal experience.

> Your eligibility to receive a HRP is as follows:
>
> 1. You should be born in HK.
> 2. You should possess an HK birth certificate
> 3. You should have any certificates showing that you are a NATURALIZED HK CHINESE CITIZEN.
> 4. You should have an HK PERMANENT IDENTITY CARD
> 5. You should have an HK PASSPORT
>
> if you have dual citizenship with any other country, for example hk passport with a US passport, that is fine, as long as you can still meet the requirements stated above.

I've seen somewhere (was it wiki that you quote) that you can apply at any Chinese embassy but the forum entries make it more likely you would need to go to HK, and likely more than once. It's long stories and read them yourself, and contact your local Chinese embassy whether you can apply with them.

The crucial point apparently is the other way round: once you had a HRP, you are no longer eligible for Chinese visa. And one more point that could be crucial for you or not a big deal: if you decide to get the HRP you are no longer under the consular protection of France in your case while in China.

In your case I would well consider whether the trouble of getting the HRP compared to regular visa on your French passport is worth it. If you do decide to get the HRP, knowledge of Chinese will surely help.

Comment: Hi @mts , many thanks for your detailed answer. I've got 2 additional questions. 1) Is having Certificates showing that you are a Naturalized HK chinese citizen is not the same thing as having an HK permanent resident identity card? 2) Does it mean that if I'm having the permit, I'll never be able to ask for a Chinese visa because of my business dealings (one of many examples)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AndyK If you have found this answer really helpful, you can accept this as a best answer. Secondly you can ask these 2 questions as a new question so that you can get answers accordingly.

Comment: Hi @AliAwan, I'll wait until tomorrow. There is no point to create an additional question when the questions I asked, stem directly from my first question. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: Hi @user102008, good man, good man

Comment: @AndyK I'm afraid I have no idea. I take 2) as entering on a business visa? For this kind of questions i would consider getting legal advice as it does seem to have very long-term implications. If [this guy](http://lawandborder.com/en/) is not able to help you you could ask them for a good France-based colleague or find one via chambers of commerce. I'm afraid I can't help more.